# Mulesoft IBM MQ connector publish-consume operation equivalent in Mule 3.9?

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, mulesoft

I am building an api which is supposed to send message to an IBM MQ and receive the response from another queue. But the operation has to appear synchronous to the caller of the api. I'm using Mule 3.9.2.

Seems Mule 4 has a connector called IBM MQ connector which has a publish conume operation to achieve this - https://docs.mulesoft.com/ibm-mq-connector/1.6/ibm-mq-publish-consume. But how do i get this done in Mule 3.9.2.
I'm currently trying to get this done with the WMQ connector and using a request-reply pattern but with no success.

Tried using request-reply,
[image]

Also had it on a separate flow,

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JoshMc - Have updated the question

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. The screenshot of the flow doesn't provide any details on the configurations. You should share the XML (text) to understand better how is the flow using each operation. Also you should provide details of "with no success.". Do you mean you are having an error? It doesn't receives a response? Did you confirm the message is sent? Kindly read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using the request-response exchange pattern available in the WMQ connector in 3.9. [image]

[image]